# Cloudant Library adding unnecessary properties while saving document

Tags: java, json, cloudant

Most probably this issue is because of JSONObject(org.json.JSONObject) is incompatible with cloudant library.

Is any alternative way to use any other Object?

I am using below cloudant libraries,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my code

```
package data.repositories;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.cloudant.client.api.*;
import com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient;
import com.cloudant.client.api.Database;
import com.cloudant.client.api.model.Response;
import util.Config;

public class DatabaseRepository {

    CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account(Config.CLOUDANT_ACCOUNT_NAME)
    .username(Config.CLOUDANT_USER_NAME)
    .password(Config.CLOUDANT_PASSWORD).build();

    public DatabaseRepository() {
JSONObject
    }

    public void Save(String dbName) {
        Database db = client.database("dbTempName", true);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{hello: data}");
        db.save(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

Document saved in cloudant database is,

```
{
  "_id": "1c7f223f74a54e7c9f4c8a713feaa537",
  "_rev": "1-a3cd12379eec936b61f899c8278c9d62",
  "map": {
    "hello": "data"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In question It seems org.json.JSONObject used And it is not compatible with cloudant client library. I tried with google object it is working good for me.

Issue got resolved by using google com.google.gson.JsonObject instead of org.json.JSONObject.

Correct Full code is given below,

```
  Database db = client.database("dbTempName", true);

  // Used google.gson.JsonObject instead of org.json.JSONObject. 
  com.google.gson.JsonParser parser = new com.google.gson.JsonParser();
  com.google.gson.JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse("{\"hello\": \"data\"}").getAsJsonObject();

  db.save(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with cloudant but my guess is JsonObject has a property called "map" that holds your json string data (probably there's a myArray property too), and cloudant serializes it into json, thus adding those *unnecessary* values.

my suggestions:

1) try to save your json string directly like db.save("{hello: data}") to avoid serialization

2) if you really need to create a JsonObject try to customize cloudant's serialization process to avoid that extra fields.

in response to comment:

from what I read [here](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.0.0/com/cloudant/client/api/Database.html#save-java.lang.Object-), then I think you need a pojo, which when serialized into json would look like:

> { 'hello' : 'data' }

which is something like:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    String hello;

    public MyClass(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }
}
```

then save it like:

> db.save(new MyClass("data"));

or you can use a hashmap instead of a pojo:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new Hashmap ...
map.put("hello", "data");
db.save(map);
```

Comment: db.save("{hello: data}") Can't work because Save method is like save(Object object)

Comment: wouldn't a method with Object parameter accept String? (String is an Object)

Comment: Compile time no error... but run time showing an error

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example in the [README for the repo](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant). It shows that you want a POJO, but you don't have to implement `Serializable`. Just create a class that has `_id` and `_rev` properties that are Strings. Then add Javascript object compatible properties as desired.

```
// A Java type that can be serialized to JSON
public class ExampleDocument {
  private String _id = "example_id";
  private String _rev = null;
  private boolean isExample;

  public ExampleDocument(boolean isExample) {
    this.isExample = isExample;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "{ id: " + _id + ",\nrev: " + _rev + ",\nisExample: " + isExample + "\n}";
  }
}

// Create an ExampleDocument and save it in the database
db.save(new ExampleDocument(true));
```

Although I haven't tried it, the Hashmap approach may work also, as discussed in this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2014/07/cloudant_on_bluemix/.

```
// create a simple doc to place into your new database
Map<String, Object> doc = new HashMap<String, Object>();
doc.put("_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
doc.put("season", "summer");
doc.put("climate", "arid");
dbc.create(doc);
```